# my webpage is not moving up to down for this css code? can anyone tell me the issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually i was building this login page to render it with another PHP page, but as i do, it makes my code unscrollable, please help me to solve this dispute.....
code is here:
the html of this CSS code may have issues, please help me to figure it out. the page **hasmaterialContainer** at the top of the body part.

```
.box {
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   opacity: 1;
   float: left;
   padding: 60px 50px 40px 50px;
   width: 100%;
   background: #fff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   transform: scale(1);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -ms-transform: scale(1);
   z-index: 5;
}

.box.back {
   transform: scale(.95);
   -webkit-transform: scale(.95);
   -ms-transform: scale(.95);
   top: -20px;
   opacity: .8;
   z-index: -1;
}

.box:before {
   content: "";
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
   left: 0;
   transform: scale(.95);
   -webkit-transform: scale(.95);
   -ms-transform: scale(.95);
   z-index: -1;
}

.overbox .title {
   color: #fff;
}

.overbox .title:before {
   background: #fff;
}

.title {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   line-height: 46px;
   font-size: 34px;
   font-weight: 700;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   color: #ED2553;
   position: relative;
}

.title:before {
   content: "";
   width: 5px;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: -50px;
   background: #ED2553;
}

.input,
.input label,
.input input,
.input .spin,
.button,
.button button .button.login button i.fa,
.material-button .shape:before,
.material-button .shape:after,
.button.login button {
   transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
   -webkit-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
   -ms-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

.material-button,
.alt-2,
.material-button .shape,
.alt-2 .shape,
.box {
   transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
   -webkit-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
   -ms-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}

.input,
.input label,
.input input,
.input .spin,
.button,
.button button {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
}

.input,
.button {
   margin-top: 30px;
   height: 70px;
}

.input,
.input input,
.button,
.button button {
   position: relative;
}

.input input {
   height: 60px;
   top: 10px;
   border: none;
   background: transparent;
}

.input input,
.input label,
.button button {
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   font-size: 24px;
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   font-weight: 300;
}

.input:before,
.input .spin {
   width: 100%;
   height: 1px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}

.input:before {
   content: "";
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   z-index: 3;
}

.input .spin {
   background: #ED2553;
   z-index: 4;
   width: 0;
}

.overbox .input .spin {
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.overbox .input:before {
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.input label {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 2;
   cursor: pointer;
   line-height: 60px;
}

.button.login {
   width: 60%;
   left: 20%;
}

.button.login button,
.button button {
   width: 100%;
   line-height: 64px;
   left: 0%;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   font-weight: 900;
   font-size: 18px;
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.button.login {
   margin-top: 30px;
}

.button {
   margin-top: 20px;
}

.button button {
   background-color: #fff;
   color: #ED2553;
   border: none;
}

.button.login button.active {
   border: 3px solid transparent;
   color: #fff !important;
}

.button.login button.active span {
   opacity: 0;
   transform: scale(0);
   -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   -ms-transform: scale(0);
}

.button.login button.active i.fa {
   opacity: 1;
   transform: scale(1) rotate(-0deg);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-0deg);
   -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(-0deg);
}

.button.login button i.fa {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   line-height: 60px;
   transform: scale(0) rotate(-45deg);
   -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(-45deg);
   -ms-transform: scale(0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.button.login button:hover {
   color: #ED2553;
   border-color: #ED2553;
}

.button {
   margin: 40px 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   z-index: 2;
}

.button button {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
}

.pass-forgot {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   font-size: 18px;
}

.click-efect {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: #ED2553;
   border-radius: 50%;
}

.overbox {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   overflow: inherit;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 60px 50px 40px 50px;
}

.overbox .title,
.overbox .button,
.overbox .input {
   z-index: 111;
   position: relative;
   color: #fff !important;
   display: none;
}

.overbox .title {
   width: 80%;
}

.overbox .input {
   margin-top: 20px;
}

.overbox .input input,
.overbox .input label {
   color: #fff;
}

.overbox .material-button,
.overbox .material-button .shape,
.overbox .alt-2,
.overbox .alt-2 .shape {
   display: block;
}

.material-button,
.alt-2 {
   width: 140px;
   height: 140px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: #ED2553;
   position: absolute;
   top: 40px;
   right: -70px;
   cursor: pointer;
   z-index: 100;
   transform: translate(0%, 0%);
   -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
   -ms-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}

.material-button .shape,
.alt-2 .shape {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.material-button .shape:before,
.alt-2 .shape:before,
.material-button .shape:after,
.alt-2 .shape:after {
   content: "";
   background: #fff;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
}

.material-button .shape:before,
.alt-2 .shape:before {
   width: 25px;
   height: 4px;
}

.material-button .shape:after,
.alt-2 .shape:after {
   height: 25px;
   width: 4px;
}

.material-button.active,
.alt-2.active {
   top: 50%;
   right: 50%;
   transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
   -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
   -ms-transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
}

body {

   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: repeat;
   min-height: inherit;
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body,
html {
   overflow: hidden;
}

.materialContainer {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 460px;
   position: relative;
   top: 25%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

*,
*:after,
*::before {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   text-decoration: none;
   list-style-type: none;
   outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Should we guess your HTML? And how would you expect a page to scroll if you set `overflow:hidden`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use the over-flow:hidden, for both BODY and HTML tag at the bottom of your style. Please check this.

```
body,
html {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from the CSS to fix your issue!

```
body,
html {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

When you declare `overflow` as `hidden` anything outside the container is invisible and unable to be scrolled to.

> With the hidden value, the overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content is hidden.